# Create multiple targets using external secret operator AWS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, external-secrets-operator

I have multiple secrets in the AWS secrets manager.
I am using an external secret operator to sync them to Kubernetes secrets.
Using external secrets, I can create Kubernetes secrets in my cluster, but I have to create separate externalSecret manifests for each AWS secret.

Here's my sample externalSecret.yaml

```
apiVersion: http://external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
spec:
  refreshInterval: 1m
  secretStoreRef:
    name: global-secret-store
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
  target:
    name: "test-secret" # Kubernetes secret name to be created
    creationPolicy: Owner
  dataFrom:
  - extract:
      key: "AWS-test-secret" # AWS secret name
```

I am looking for a way to create multiple Kubernetes secrets for AWS secrets manager secrets using a single external secrets file.

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably, it is not possible to generate multiple Kubernetes Secret objects from a single ExternalSecret resource.